# Recursive CTE check if record exists at any level then get all children (folder structure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I'm trying to check using a recursive CTE if a user has access to a folder and if they do, then the folder and all children

The structure is basic

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Folders](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
  [ParentId] [int] NULL)
```

This is the table that links a user to a folder

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FolderAccess](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [FolderId] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Using the following example data

`SELECT * FROM Folders`

| Id | ParentId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Root |
| 2 | 1 | Sub folder 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Sub folder 2 |
| 4 | 3 | Sub folder 3 |
| 5 | 4 | Sub folder 4 |
| 6 | 5 | Sub folder 5 |

`SELECT UserId, FolderId FROM FolderAccess`

| UserId | FolderId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

The user above has access to folder `3` so indirectly has access to folder `4,5,6`

I should be able to put any `FolderId` `3,4,5,6` and get results but using folder id `2` would return nothing as that is higher up the hierarchy.

```sql
DECLARE @FolderId INT = 3
;WITH TopDownFolderHierarchy (Id, ParentId , Name)
AS
(
    SELECT fold.Id, fold.ParentId, fold.Name FROM Folders fold 
    WHERE fold.ID = @FolderId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT parents.Id, parents.ParentId, parents.Name FROM Folders parents 
    INNER JOIN TopDownFolderHierarchy cte on cte.Id = parents.ParentId
    
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below tries first to list folders the user has access to then the required hierarchy among accessible folders

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 1;
DECLARE @FolderId INT = 5;

WITH
AccessibleHierarchy (Id, ParentId , Name) AS
(
    SELECT fold.Id, fold.ParentId, fold.Name FROM Folders fold 
    WHERE fold.[CreatorUserId] = @UserId or fold.ID in (select [FolderId] from [FolderAccess] where [UserId] = @UserId)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT parents.Id, parents.ParentId, parents.Name FROM Folders parents 
    INNER JOIN AccessibleHierarchy cte on cte.Id = parents.ParentId
),
QueriedHierarchy (Id, ParentId , Name) AS
(
    SELECT distinct fold.Id, fold.ParentId, fold.Name FROM AccessibleHierarchy fold 
    WHERE fold.ID = @FolderId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT parents.Id, parents.ParentId, parents.Name FROM Folders parents 
    INNER JOIN QueriedHierarchy cte on cte.Id = parents.ParentId
)
select * from QueriedHierarchy
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=337c7c0f5915e57f77bd163a90b8b33f)

edit: added use of a CreatorUserId column in Folders and added a distinct keyword in QueriedHierarchy in case there a hierarchy is allowed by multiple CreatorUserId/FolderAccess

Comment: Would it be possible to also include here where folders are created by that user, this means you have access not just when a record exists in FolderAccess but when the CreatorUserId of the FolderTable is also @UserId?

Comment: @StevenYates Chek the edit